# paste a text in two place at the same time in the nano editor

Tags: text-editor, nano

I have a text file:

```
#"UDP-/32", "UA", 0, "any", "any", udp, 0.0.0.0/0, /32, {x, x, x}
```

Is there a way so I can paste a text before /32 at the same time, like multiple cursors in the vscode?

The result be:

```
#"UDP-TEXT/32", "UA", 0, "any", "any", udp, 0.0.0.0/0, TEXT/32, {x, x, x}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"paste" at the same time? No. A paste is one time so you would need to repeat it each time you want it pasted.

You can do control-f and do a replace (with of without confirm) of /32 with TEXT/32.

All other options will be outside of VSCode (like using `sed`).